# Redirect to SSL for specific URLs only

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirect, https

I want to force SSL www by re-directing only for some URL patterns.

for example,

Force SSL www redirect:

```
http://example.com/asia/fewf -> https://www.example/asia/fewfwe
http://example.com/africa/foo/bar/1/ -> https://www.example/africa/foo/bar/1/
```

Do-not do anything:

```
http://example.com/europe/1 -> http://example.com/europe/1
http://www.example.com/europe/1 -> http://www.example.com/europe/1
```

I've tried adding this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/asia[^/]*/.*)$ https://www.example.com$1
```

But, it results in an error: "Too mant redirections"

Comment: What have you [tried](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)?

Comment: @HBruijn: Sorry, I forgot to add that part. Edited my question.

Comment: That typically happens when you have the same document root for both your http and https sites and use .htacces. (There are many reason I discourage .htaccess ) Set your redirect configuration in the VirtualHost stanza of your apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you're getting too many redirections is because the RedirectMatch will fire even when the URL is requested at https so it keeps redirecting over and over even once it already becomes https.

I'd suggest solving this with mod_rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/asia[^/]*/.*)$ https://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

When you're testing it out, I'd recommend instead of `R=301`, just have `R` because that doesn't cause the browser to permanently cache the redirect which can make troubleshooting complicated.

Comment: This is giving a 500 error. http://dpaste.com/1RXBQXD

Comment: @xan Sorry, I typed RewriteCond by mistake instead of RewriteRule for the last line.  I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @xan Was the updated answer able to solve your issue?  If so, I'd appreciate if you mark it as accepted so I can get credit for it.  If not, let me know what you're running into. Thanks

Comment: No. It still gave me the 500 internal server error. I skipped the htaccess file and added basic redirection rules in PHP to the file which gets accessed after the htaccess one.